# Loop through array collection using same eventlistener for each item

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

```
var lstservices:Array = ["Attachment","Dev","Domain","service"]
    for each(var servicename:String in lstservices)
            {

            var webs:WebService = new WebService();
            var url:String= "http://XXXX/XXXX/"+ servicename +".asmx?wsdl";
            webs.wsdl = url;    
            webs.loadWSDL();
            webs.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,fault);
            webs.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,GetDataFromService);
            webs.makeObjectsBindable=false;
            webs.GetAll();
            srvs = servicename.substr(0,servicename.length-7);

            }
```

as you see in the code event listener is added each time and the WSDL is changing each time. the problem is when the loop finishes the control goes to the result event Listener with the result from the first WSDL but the last variable in the loop is holding the last element of the Array not the first one as the WSDL result. I hope the questions is clear for you guys thanks. I used action script in flex

Comment: sounds like you need to wait to get a response before proceeding to the next one

Comment: Looks like scope is your issue.

Comment: I think Ronnie is right, all calls in actionscripts are async and need to wait to get the result before proceeding. now each  service is somehow stays on the stack and after the loop it start coming one by one with the result on the result lisnter but the srvs variable is not doing so, it just keeps the last value.

Comment: but now when I add  webs.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,waitandprocess); it never goes to this method. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code placed?
It is going to the last item because the last is the only one. You keep overwriting `var webs:WebService` so the first one doesn't exist anymore, there is no existing reference to it.

Comment: srvs is a public variable, what I want is that the srvs and service name to be the same for each loop in the event listener result. when the loop finishes control goes to the result listener and the first result set is for the "attachment service" which is the first element in the array in my above code but the srvs variable is alwasy the last variable which is "service" in my array. I want to hold attachment value for both wsdl result and srvs variable. hope it is clear now. if not please let me know I will try to explain in some other way. thanks